# How to replace "\n" in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I want to replace "\n" in Applescript. Whenever I write that, it just brings whatever is after `\n` to the next line. How do I do that?

```
set newVar to my replaceText("\n/blah-blah", "")
```

EDIT:

```
set newVar to my replaceText(linefeed, "", newVar)
log newVar
```

`newVar` still prints with `\n` towards the end.

Comment: Tried that, it didnt do anything. Printed the same thing again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should catch them all:

```
set oldText to "line 1
line 2
line 3"

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {return & linefeed, return, linefeed, character id 8233, character id 8232}
set newText to text items of oldText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {" "}
set newText to newText as text
```

using "blah\n" as oldText[image]

Comment: Can you please explain the first 3 lines? This is my first day of AppleScript learning so apologies if its a stupid question. Specially what you meant by line1, line2 and line3?

Comment: Assuming my oldText is already set. Copied the last 4 lines. Printed newText, still the same :-/. P.S: My old Text is "blah\n". Linefeed attached at the end of a word is still a linefeed right?

Comment: setting oldText to "blah\n" returns "blah "

Comment: `log newText` should return `blah` right? I am just not getting it.

Comment: try return newText ... also what do you mean by Printed newText?

Comment: By printing I meant `log`. Using `return newText` shows "blah\\n".

Comment: I have posted code that works... please post the code you are using so I can see where the disconnect is.

Comment: Just that section works in a new file. Its a huge code. I will have to debug what am I doing wrong. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9):

Found this solution to your problem, Go to preferences-->Editing and check Escape tabs and line breaks in strings

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1395073

Comment: I am trying to print and debug. Nothing prints after `set newVar to my replaceText("\\n/blah-blah", "")` now.

Comment: That trick worked, now I can write `\n' but again its not working. Any clues on that. Is the above syntax wrong?

Comment: My AppleScript isn't super strong, but maybe this would help for what you are trying to do: http://foolsworkshop.com/applescript/2008/05/an-applescript-replace-text-method/

Answer (score 3):

Use the `linefeed` [AppleScript constant](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-DontLinkElementID_621):

```
set newVar to my replaceText(linefeed & "/blah-blah", "")
```

Comment: Tried this too :( Still doesnt replace it, prints the same thing.